# How to perform a power-analysis on a single coefficient in a MLR model in R?

Tags: multiple-regression, cross-validation, statistical-power

I am interested in performing a power analysis for a single coefficient for a multiple regression model that contains 3 covariates.

The population of interest is the male subjects (n = 140), and I then stratified by the males based on body size (n = 64). The MLR is using the stratified male subset (n=64). I want to know if this reduction in sample size could reduce the statistical power of testing the significance of a model coefficient.

I tried fixing 2 of the 3 coefficients with their least squares estimate, and then performed a repeated sample of size n=64 with replacement of the 140 males over 10,000 iterations. I stored the p-values of the coefficient of interest to test if any were found to be significant. I was hoping to find the power by taking the proportion of p-values < 0.05 to p-value > 0.05. Zero of these were found to be significant despite an average coefficient value of 3.65. I'm not sure if this is correct, and/or if there is a better alternative out there.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The p-value of a single parameter in R is equal to the p-value for the change in R^2 when adding that parameter to the model (which you find with anova(fit1, fit2).

This means that you can the pwr.f2.test() function in the pwr() package, for the change in R^2.